# What's difference between + and - in the list in org mode

Tags: org-mode, list

I find I can create bullets with the - and + both. How can I decide when to use + and -

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They make no difference, they are just a style of bullet and have no meaning.

There are many different bullet types you can use, for sorted and non-sorted lists.

You can use `org-shiftright` (<kbd>s-right</kbd>) and `org-shiftleft` (<kbd>s-left</kbd>) to cycle through bullet types to see them all. It is up to you to decide which one you would like to use.

See also the docs of `org-cycle-list-bullet` to see all possible bullet types.